# Problem with autoloader and namespaces

Tags: plugin-development, namespace, autoloading

I'm writing a simple plugin with oop and using namespaces and autoloading. Here is my main file:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', array(My_Test_Plugin::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup'));

class My_Test_Plugin
{
    /**
     * Plugin instance.
     *
     * @see get_instance()
     * @type object
     */
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    /**
     * URL to this plugin's directory.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    public $plugin_url = '';
    /**
     * Path to this plugin's directory.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    public $plugin_path = '';

    /**
     * Access this plugin’s working instance
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @since   2012.09.13
     * @return  object of this class
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Used for regular plugin work.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @return  void
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url = plugins_url('/', __FILE__);
        $this->plugin_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
        $this->load_language('vt-plugin');

        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoload'));

    }
    /**
     * @param $class
     *
     */
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        $class = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);

        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            $class_full_path = $this->plugin_path . 'includes/' . $class . '.php';
            if (file_exists($class_full_path)) {
                require $class_full_path;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `includes/PostTypes` directory there is a file called `Book.php` and it's containing this:

```
namespace Book;

class Book {
    public function vt_create_book_post_type() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Books', 'vt-plugin' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Book', 'vt-plugin' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Books', 'vt-plugin' ),
            ),
        );

        register_post_type( 'book', $args );
    }
}
```

It just registers a simple post type. Now my question is Where I should use my `init` action to register post type?

I used this code in the `plugin_setup` function in my main file:

```
add_action( 'init', array('Book', 'vt_register_book_post_type') );
```

But it gave me this error:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback
```

**Update**
If I change my autoloader function to this:

```
public function autoload($class)
    {
        $class = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);

        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            $class_full_path = $this->plugin_path . 'includes/' . $class . '.php';
            if (file_exists($class_full_path)) {
                require $class_full_path;
                echo $class_full_path; 
            }
        }
    }
```

And echo the full path inside the if statement, it does not echo anything and I think this means that files aren't included.

Answer (score 1):

The callback `[ 'Book', 'vt_register_book_post_type' ]` is adding a hook to the static method `vt_register_book_post_type` in the `Book` class of the global namespace.

If you want to add a callback to a static class of the Book namespace, you need to use `[ '\Book\Book\', 'vt_register_book_post_type' ]` as a callback, but that will also cause a warning or error because your method is not static. You can declare your method `static`, but what I think you want to do is something like this:

```
namespace Book;
class book {
  public function vt_create_book_post_type() {
    $labels = [
      'name'                  => _x( 'Books', 'vt-plugin' ),
      'singular_name'         => _x( 'Book', 'vt-plugin' ),
      'menu_name'             => _x( 'Books', 'vt-plugin' ),
    ];
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
  }
}
$book = new book();
\add_action( 'init', [ $book, 'vt_create_book_post_type' ] );
```

There's nothing wrong with your autoloader. Or at least that's not what's causing the error.

Comment: I corrected my code based on your answer, but still it doesn't create the post type. And also there is no error or warning.

Comment: `$book = new book();` and the `add_action()` need to be in a file that has already been included. It's hard for me to imagine how this could both not register the post type and not produce an error of some kind.

Comment: I updated the question with some more info about the autoloader function. I still think something is wrong with it.

Comment: Is the autoloader being run at all? What's `$class`? What's `$class_full_path`?